# Youtube Embed: How to avoid fullscreen and no info

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, embed

How can I avoid fullscreen when playing a video in Swift 2.0?

```
let Code:NSString = "<iframe width=255 height=135 src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/eVk3TMB1JWY?autoplay=1&fs=0 frameborder=0 allowfullscreen=false></>"
```

I both tried fs=0 and allowfullscreen=false but neither work.

When the video shows up in my webview, the info about the video is also shown; how can I avoid this too?

Comment: I think google has released an lOS SDK for youtube. That might be able to give you more options for how to display videos.

Comment: Actually I think iPhone normally forces any video to go fullscreen. Try it for the iPad just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, it sounds like you want to play the video "inline."  Pass in whatever width and height values you want into the UIWebView constructor to allow inLine playback without the video popping open to its full screen player.

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame) // or your custom CGRect

self.view.addSubview(webView)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(webView)

webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

let videoID = "zN-GGeNPQEg" // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zN-GGeNPQEg

let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete allowfullscreen from the link. Your link will look like this:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/eVk3TMB1JWY?autoplay=1&fs=0 frameborder=0 >